# Redirect from www to nonwww on Apache

Tags: apache

I have a problem with redirecting my site to non www. I actually have NextCloudPlus on my RPi, but I want to use my RPI to host some other simple sites.
Almost all is looking good, but when I enter http://www.example.com I get redirect to https://www.example.com instead of non www.

curl -I http://www.example.com

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 08 Jun 2018 11:04:05 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload
Location: https://www.example.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/nextcloud
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/examplecom
  ServerName examplecom
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

/sites-enabled/examplecom.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost _default_:443>
    SSLEngine on
      SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/examplecom/fullchain.pem
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/examplecom/privkey.pem
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you ask for `http://www.example.com`, this is catched by Apache to go to the default VirtualHost, since it is on port 80. In there you redirect to `https://%{SERVER_NAME}`, and here SERVER_NAME == www.example.com. Remove that default VirtualHost and you will be fine.

Also, ServerName should be the domain name you expect for that VirtualHost.  I would put:

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
```